# Split a string into an array and trim each element

Tags: postgresql

I've worked out how to split a string into an array, but I'm not sure how I can use a trim function on each element to remove any whitespace.

Right now, when I select and separate the field, I use the following syntax (where ";" is the delimiter):

```
string_to_array("Column", ';') as "SplitColumn"
```

But if "Column" contains "something ; like ; this", the output would be

```
"SplitColumn":["something ", " like ", " this"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access each elements of the array, trim them, and build back the array.
Don't forget the inner select.

```sql
select array(select trim(unnest(array[' a ',' b ',' c '])));
 array
---------
 {a,b,c}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `TRIM` function along with the `string_to_array()` function;

```
SELECT
  TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM UNNEST(string_to_array("Column", ';'))) AS "TrimmedSplitColumn"
FROM
  your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT TRIM(both ' ' FROM unnest(string_to_array("Column", ';')))
  ) as "SplitColumn"
FROM your_table;
```

**string_to_array("Column", ';')** splits the "Column" into an array using ';' as the delimiter. **unnest** turns the array into a set of rows and wrapping it  in Array would convert it back to an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can break the input string into an array using the `string_to_array` function and the `;` delimiter. Leading and trailing whitespace will be used to generate an array with entries that contain them. The `array_to_string` function can then be used to remove the whitespace from each entry. This function removes any excess whitespace before concatenating the array's items into a single string. Just like in the example I am mentioning

```
SELECT array_to_string(string_to_array("Column", ';'), ';') as "CleanedColumn"
FROM your_table;
```

Using the `;` delimiter, this query separates the input string into an array, cleans up each element by removing any whitespace, and then puts the array back together. You'll get a string without any whitespace.

Comment: `array_to_string` does **not** remove whitespace, so you are splitting the text and then putting it back together as it was originally.